# Javascript: check if word in input is placed after an other word

Tags: javascript

I have a question but I can't find the answer for my problem. Hope you can help me!

Here's my HTML:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="one">
    <input type="text" id="two">
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
$('#one').on('input', function(){
var value = $(this).val();
if (value.includes("@") && value.includes(".com"))
{
   $('#two').focus();
   }
  });
```

**[Demo](https://codepen.io/BramB/pen/dyVWMor)**

**What this script does** 
I'm making a login form where the input focuses on the second input when a user has typed his email. In my code: it focuses on the next input when the first input detects an '@' symbol and the text '.com'.

**But here's the problem**
Lets say your email is: 'john.computer@gmail.com'. My script focuses on the second input after you typed the '@' symbol, because the input already contains '.com' and '@'.

**My Question**
What javascript do I need to add that checks if '.com' is typed after the '@' symbol?

Comment: You probably don't need JS. [HTML5 has very extensive form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation).

Comment: how about changing the input type of id #one to type='email' instead of type='text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex: `@.*\.com`

```js
if (/@.*\.com/.test(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf))

```
if (value.includes("@") && value.includes(".com") && value.indexOf("@") < value.indexOf(".com"))
```

I just find both locations and compare them. `@` should be found in an earlier index than `.com`. However, here lies another problem in your code. That is not all emails ended with `.com`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) is some solution to solve the problem or you can just use this one

```
if (value.includes("@") && value.includes(".") && value.indexOf("@") < value.indexOf("."))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to update focus once the user has entered a valid email address. For tips on that, check out the answers to this classic question: [What's the best way to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

To answer your question more directly, you could create a regular expression (RegExp) to check if `.com` is typed after the `@` symbol.

```
const comAfterAtSymbol = new RegExp('@.*\.com')
if (comAfterAtSymbol.test(value)) {
  ...
}
```